# Window GotFocus event not firing

Tags: wpf

I couldnt get the `GotFocus()` event fired in the WPF window by clicking. But if I click any controls, it will be fired.

My requirement is as follows: I have a hostwindow which has a viewport with two datagrids which can host user controls. I do animations like flip and fade on this user controls. I am using a transparent background(glass effect) for the controls. But when one user control get on top of the other, both of them overlap. So I want to make the top one opaque when the user click on one user control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activated%28VS.85%29.aspx) event, as GotFocus is intended to be used only with controls.